# Simple determinant calculation

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant

> \begin{vmatrix} 
> 1 & -2 & 2 \\
> 1 & -2 & -2\\
> 2 & -2 & 1 
> \end{vmatrix}

It is fairly easy I just want to reassure the steps are correct:

\begin{vmatrix} 
1 & -2 & 2 \\
1 & -2 & -2\\
2 & -2 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}  Taking out $-2^{n}$ when $n$ is the number of rows/columns in this case $n=1$ (the second column)

$$-2 \begin{vmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & -2\\
2 & 1 & 1 
\end{vmatrix} $$

Reducing column 2 from column 1 as no effect on the determinant

$$-2 \begin{vmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & -2\\
1 & 1 & 1 
\end{vmatrix} $$

Using Laplace expansion on the first column

$$(-2)*1[1*(-2)-2*1]=8.$$

Comment: Looks good to me. The Rule of Sarrus is a nice method as well for $3\times 3$ and a quick check of your work. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus

Comment: Even easier : $$R_1'=R_1-R_2$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{vmatrix} 
1 & -2 & 2 \\
1 & -2 & -2\\
2 & -2 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}
$$R'_1=R_1-R_2 \space R'_2=R_2-R_3 $$
$$\begin{vmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 4 \\
-1 & 0 & -3\\
2 & -2 & 1 
\end{vmatrix}
=8$$